# What informations leaks during send mail programatically from google account

Tags: c#, email, gmail, privacy, privacy-policy

Imagine if you are sending an email by the gmail.com using web online interface so entering the website of google, then compose mail and send it. In this case your ip address is not revealed to the receiver of mail. In details of mail header there are google server's informations.

If it is good or not it is a topic for a big discussion, have some advantages and disadvantages... However only one way to get someone's ip address so location is court way and lawyer sending a document to google with a question to reveal ip address of sender of the particular mail. Am I right ?

What is my wondering right now is if I have same privacy (assuming I claim true above) in case of using a program and perform a function like this:

```
    public static void SendAnEmail(MailAccount mailAccount, Mail mail)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = mailAccount.host;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 10000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailAccount.username, mailAccount.password);

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(mailAccount.username, mail.mailTo, mail.subject, mail.body);
        mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        mailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

        client.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

where Mail contain subject, body and mailTo strings and MailAccount have username, password and host, so all required informations to send an email. The whole code is written in C# by the way.

Imagine that I have a program which is doing some office work and at the end of some activities is going to send an email using code above of course using a google host (an account created at google website). Then - what is happening ? What is in mail details header ? My computer ip address or google server ones ? Do this mail contain some more information like mac address of network card or my motherboard.

I hope you understand my question, if it is not clear, please ask questions about my situation. Any suggestion how to obtain such a privacy using "mailing by code" would be appreciated. However explanation of the situation it is what I am looking for.

Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: if your question is "if i send the mail programmatically, will google still know where the request came from?", then the answer is yes, they will. If you don't want to be tracked, use a VPN.

Comment: almost, because for me is important what is displayed to receiver of the mail, google may known user of my app, however the receiver of the mail should not be able to known user of my app until the law is not broken (then the court way is possible)

Comment: Anyone may provide some sure opinion for yes or not ?